# Javascript, URL parsing, conditional CSS style.display on navigation menu

Tags: javascript, css, url, conditional-statements

Alright, so for some reason my code is not working here... It is a vertical HTML/CSS navigation menu created with `<ul>` and `<li>`s..... each list item has a sub nav which will display another list. Basically, I want to make the code read the current URL and conditionally hide (`display: none`) the sub-navigations that do not apply to the specified URL...

Obviously I would repeat this code for each of the navigation items.

Why is it that when I am asking the element ID to `display:none`, it won't work... ugh. Please help.

Please see attached. Thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var URL = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;

    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    document.write(URL);
        document.write("<br/>");
    document.write(pathArray[1]);
        document.write("<br/>");
    document.write(pathArray[2]);
        document.write("<br/>");
    document.write(pathArray[3]);
        document.write("<br/>");
    if (pathArray[2] == "general")
     {
      document.getElementById("cd").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById("sd").style.display = 'none';
         } 


</script>

    <!-- Left Navigation starts here -->
            <!-- if IE -->
            <div id="IE_nav">
            <!-- endif IE -->
            <div id="left_nav">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li class="nav_button">NAV ITEM 1</li></a>
                                <li class="sub_nav_box" id="gd">
                                    <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                    <a href="#"><li class="nav_button">NAV ITEM 2</li></a>
                                <li id="cd" class="sub_nav_box">        
                                    <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                    <a href="#"><li class="nav_button">NAV ITEM 3</li></a>
                                <li class="sub_nav_box" id="id">
                                    <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                                    </ul></ul>
                            </div></div>
```

Comment: It cut off above... It meant to start with Alright, so for some reason my code is not working here... It is a vertical HTML/CSS navigation menu created with and '<ul> &<li>'s.....

Comment: Thanks thirty dot for the edit

Answer (score 0):

That is you are trying to access some DOM elements before they have been defined

Move your script right after your html and it will work.

```
<!-- Left Navigation starts here -->
......
```

then your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var URL = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/" +      window.location.pathname;
......
```

or for even better result use the dom ready event to trigger your script. This can be easily achieved using jquery

```
$(function () {
// your script here
...
});
```

Comment: Hey, Ibu. There's no point in loading the entire jQuery library just to be able to use the document ready handler.

Comment: that is absolutely true, but think about it, the onload event is not the best option either. the navigation will show first then it will disappear. it will have a an ugly effect on the page. of course i can point him out how to use the DOM ready event, which is complicated for crossbrowser, but why not just use a 19k jquery file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the DOM you are asking JavaScript to perform actions on is not loaded at the time of execution. I suggest placing all JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
   //HERE
}
</script>
```

Now, besides that, you have some other problems.

1) You end up with two DIVs if the browser is IE and you problably only need one. You also end up with an extra closing div if it is not IE because you are missing the conditional for the "if IE" div closing statement.

<!-- if IE -->
<div id="IE_nav">
<!-- endif IE -->
<div id="left_nav">

2) As per the HTML 4, XHTML and HTML5 specs an `<ul>` element can only contain `<li>` elements as direct children. Your `<ul>` contains `<a>` elements as direct children. Place the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>` that it currently wraps. Reverse the two.

3) `<a>` is an inline element (unless set otherwise with CSS) while `<li>` is a block level element (unless set otherwise with CSS). You should not place block level elements inside inline elements, but the other way around. Fixing point 2, would fix point 3 as well.

Good luck.